# Ansible check for java process started executing

Tags: java, ansible

I am facing an issue, that sometimes application is not starting but it is creating an empty output file

How do I check if the java process is invoked  before proceeding to the next step.

kindly note that I have a next step to check if java process is started...

Also is there any way to go back to the previous step in ansible based on a condition??

This issue is happening only intermittently

```
- name: Run Application
  shell: "nohup java  -jar {{ filename }}.jar > {{ appname }}.out  2>&1 & "
  args:
    chdir: "{{ jarpath }}"
  environment:
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/opt/java/bin/"
  tags: start
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you use systemctl script instead of nohup? Maybe it will resolve.

Comment: What if the system doesn’t have systemd daemon?

Comment: Ansible can manage `sysv`, `upstart`.... through the [`service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html)